# How to generate a Quasar SSR full-stack application?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

**Context:** I am migrating from Nuxt to Quasar framework, and initially I want to port my full-stack apps from Nuxt to Quasar SSR mode. When using Nuxt, apps are full-stack by default, we just need to place backend related files in the server-directory (see https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#server-directory).

**Question:** I have already created my first Quasar application and added the SSR mode, but I could not find anything similar to Nuxt server-directory :-( So the question is: Does Quasar offer something similar to Nuxt server-directory? How to generate a Quasar SSR full-stack application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think Quasar offers something similar to *server-directory* out-of-the-box, but Quasar is a quite flexible framework, and we can easily achieve "SSR full-stack capabilities" by using a [Quasar SSR-middleware](https://quasar.dev/quasar-cli-vite/developing-ssr/ssr-middleware) :-)

## The idea is:

SSR-middleware is an additional layer where all browser-requests are supposed to come through. Therefore, all we need to do is to add an additional SSR-middleware to intercept browser-requests when trying to hit a specific route (in this case, `/api/*`). Step-by-step:

> Disclaimer: it works only when running Quasar in SSR mode, of course.

1. Considering that we have already created our Quasar application, and have already added the SSR mode (`npm init quasar && cd my-app && quasar mode add ssr`), let's add an additional SSR-middleware "api" with the command:

```
quasar new ssrmiddleware api
```

2. After that we need to include our SSR-middleware into `quasar.config.js`:

```
ssr: {
    ...
    middlewares: [
        'api', // <= this is our SSR-middleware (keep this as first one)
        'render' // keep this as last one
    ]
},
...
```

3. And the last step is to implement the browser-requests interception into our SSR-middleware file `src-ssr/middlewares/api.ts`:

```
export default ssrMiddleware(async ({ app, resolve }) => {
    app.all(resolve.urlPath('*'),(req, res, next) => {
        if (req.url.substring(0, 4) === '/api') {
            // Here we can implement our backend NodeJS/Express related operations.
            // See the example below "Real-life example", which provides
            // something similar to Next/Nuxt server-directory functionality.
            res.status(200).send(`Hi! req.method: ${req.method}, req.url: ${req.url}`);
        } else {
            next();
        }
    });
});
```

Now we can start our Quasar SSR application, and see our API in action by pointing the browser to http://localhost:9100/api/foo/bar/
Response => Hi! req.method: GET, req.url: /api/foo/bar/

---

## Real-life example:

*updated according to [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13765033/david-wolf)'s suggestion. Thanks :-)*

1. In order to provide something similar to Next/Nuxt server-directory functionality, we need to include some additional lines of code into our SSR-middleware file `src-ssr/middlewares/api.ts`. The example below maps all available API-Handler (see apiHandlers object) and select them to handle browser requests according to the request URL:

```
import { ssrMiddleware } from 'quasar/wrappers';

const apiHandlers: { [key: string]: any } = {
  'req-info': import('../../src/api/req-info'),
  version: import('../../src/api/version'),
};

export default ssrMiddleware(async ({ app, resolve }) => {
  app.all(resolve.urlPath('*'), async(req, res, next) => {
    if (req.url.substring(0, 4) === '/api') {
      try {
        const path = req.url.split('?')[0].substring(5);
        const apiHandler = await apiHandlers[path];
        if (apiHandler) {
          await apiHandler.default(req, res);
        } else {
          res.sendStatus(404);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        res.sendStatus(500);
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
});
```

2. And after that we just need to create our NodeJS/Express API-Handlers in the folder `/src/api/`.

- Example #1: `/src/api/version.ts`:

```
import type { Request, Response } from 'express';
export default function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  const version = require('../../package.json').version;
  res.status(200).send(version);
}
```

- Example #2: `/src/api/req-info.ts`:

```
import type { Request, Response } from 'express';
export default function (req: Request, res: Response) {
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html');
  res.status(200).send(`
  <ul>
    <li>req.url: ${req.url}</li>
    <li>req.method: ${req.method}</li>
    <li>req.query: ${JSON.stringify(req.query)}</li>
  </ul>`);
}
```

I hope it helps, thanks!
If so, please vote-up :-)

StackBlitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-uocha6

Comment: Is there a way to send the HTML from example #2 from an HTML file? Trying to `.sendFile` does not work because the html file in `src-ssr` is not getting included in the build (as far as I can tell).

Comment: Hi DevJem!

Note that `sendFile` express API imports the file during runtime _(instead of compilation time)_, which means that we need to use file pathnames according to the "Quasar SSR build output" _(or "Quasar src folder", in case of development mode)_. And note also that only files stored in the `./src/public/` directory are automatically copied into the quasar 'Quasar SSR build output' (execute `quasar build -m ssr`, and check the contents of your `./dist/ssr/` folder).

I will continue in the comment below (due to the comment length limitation)...

Comment: Continuing from the comment above (due to the comment length limitation)...

So, I think the simplest solution to use `sendFile` API is:
1. place your "file.html" inside the folder `./src/public/` (instead of inside src-ssr).
2. Adjust the "Example #2" to import "file.html" from `/server/` folder (in case of production build) or from `/public/` folder (in case of development mode):

I will continue in the comment below (due to the comment length limitation)...

Comment: line 1: `import type { Request, Response } from 'express';` ... 
line 2: `const path = require('path');`
line 3: `export default function (req: Request, res: Response) {`
line 4: `const publicDir = process.env.DEV ? '../../public' : 'client';`
line 5: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, publicDir, 'file.html'));`
line 6: `}`

Comment: Sorry for the messy code format above... StackOverflow does not support code-blocks in comments :-( Anyway, I hope it helps :-)

Comment: Samer, thank you for your help! With the current configuration of middleware through Quasar I was able to use `const publicDir = process.env.DEV ? 'public' : 'client'` once I moved my html into the public folder. Last piece was setting the express view engines "views" directory to that `publicDir` with `app.set('views', publicDir)` and I was able to reference it simply with `res.render('file.html')`.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach might be using [Nuxt-Quasar](https://github.com/Maiquu/nuxt-quasar). I'm currently in the process of migrating from NuxtV2/VuetifyV2 to NuxtV3/QuasarV2 and this plugin has been amazing so far. The power of Nuxt with the components of Quasar, it might save you some time.

Answer (score 0):

I like the approach of Samer Eberlin, however there is a big drawback, it relies on the source folder, since handlers are dynamically imported from the `src` directory at runtime. This means that the production build `dist` is not standalone, since the API handlers are not bundled into the production build.

Here is a version that includes the routes in the production build (with TypeScript and ES Modules support).

#### ./src/api/_routes.ts

Routes configuration, keys are the api paths, `/ping` will be `/api/ping`, and the values should be function that will resolve to a module import.

```ts
const routes = {
    '/ping': () => import('./ping'),
}

export default routes
```

#### ./src/api/ping.ts

Example api route/handler, should have a default export.

```ts
import type { Request, Response } from 'express'

export default function (req: Request, res: Response) {
    res.status(200).send('pong')
}
```

#### ./src-ssr/middlewares/api.ts

Quasar ssr middleware to intercept and map the request path to the configured routes, will raise `404` when not mapped, `500` on error and otherwise whatever the handler is doing.

```ts
import { ssrMiddleware } from 'quasar/wrappers'
import routes from '../../src/api/_routes'
import type { Request, Response } from 'express'
import { parse } from 'url'

export default ssrMiddleware(async ({ app, resolve }) => {
    app.all(resolve.urlPath('*'), async (req: Request, res: Response, next) => {
        const { pathname } = parse(req.url)
        if (!pathname || !pathname.startsWith('/api')) {
            return next()
        }

        const path = pathname.replace(/^\/api/, '')

        if (!Object.keys(routes).includes(path)) {
            res.sendStatus(404).end()
            return
        }

        console.log(`API hit on ${path}`)

        try {
            const handler = (await routes[path as keyof typeof routes]())
                .default
            handler(req, res)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            res.sendStatus(500).end()
        }
    })
})
```